# How do you take out the space between lines after line break?

Tags: html, css, word-spacing

I have two lines where I want them to be right below each other so I put a line break between them.  But after that, there is this huge gap in between the lines.

**How do I keep the lines ("h8 adr" and "h8 no")separated but leave no space between the separation?**

**My code:**

```css
.adr {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px;
  padding-top: 65px;
  padding-bottom: 65px;
  padding left: 65px;
  padding-right: 65px;
  font-size: 500%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.no {
  font-stretch: condensed;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class='adr'>

  A place
  <br>
  <h8 class='ad'>
    4567 postal code An Address
  </h8>
  <br>
  <h8 class='no'>
    Phone: 123-456 789 Fax: 123-456 789
  </h8>
</h1>
```

Comment: I'm wondering, why you need an `<h8>`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22638799/is-it-possible-to-create-html-tags-h7-h8-h9-and-so-on

Answer (score 1):

Take away the second `<br>` and make `.no` have `display: block`:

```css
.adr {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px;
  padding-top: 65px;
  padding-bottom: 65px;
  padding left: 65px;
  padding-right: 65px;
  font-size: 500%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.no {
  font-stretch: condensed;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h1 class='adr'>

  A place
  <br>
  <h8 class='ad'>
    4567 postal code An Address
  </h8>
  <h8 class='no'>
    Phone: 123-456 789 Fax: 123-456 789
  </h8>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to simply turn `.no` into a **[block-level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)** by applying
**[`display: block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)**. Then you can adjust the offset by using **[negative margins](http://css-101.org/negative-margin/index.php)**:

```
.no {
  display: block;
  margin-top: -24px;
}
```

The exact negative margin to use depends on **exactly** where you want the second text to sit, but `-24px` will place the element at the exact bottom of the preceding element:

```css
.adr {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px;
  padding-top: 65px;
  padding-bottom: 65px;
  padding-left: 65px;
  padding-right: 65px;
  font-size: 500%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.no {
  font-stretch: condensed;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -24px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class='adr'> A place
  <br>
  <h8 class='ad'>
    4567 postal code An Address
  </h8>
  <br>
  <h8 class='no'>
    Phone: 123-456 789 Fax: 123-456 789
  </h8>
</h1>
```

Also, note that:

- Your `.adr` has `padding left` instead of `padding-left`. That's fixed in the above example.
- You also have a `<br />` in between the two elements, which you could
  remove, though note that you'll need to adjust the offset if you do.
- `<h8>` would be  a [**custom** element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements); the **[standard HTML headings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements)** only go up to `h6`.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the line break and throw that address into a paragraph tag. This way you don't have to change any styles. If that isn't close enough changing the display to block and adjusting margin/padding will do the trick. Hope this helps

```css
.adr {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px;
  padding-top: 65px;
  padding-bottom: 65px;
  padding left: 65px;
  padding-right: 65px;
  font-size: 500%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.no {
  font-stretch: condensed;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class='adr'>
  A place
  <br>
  <h8 class='ad'>
    4567 postal code An Address
  </h8>
  
  <h8 class='no'>
    <p>Phone: 123-456 789 Fax: 123-456 789</p>
  </h8>
</h1>
```