# HTML/CSS - How do I align three different elements in different way in a heady

Tags: css, html

I have researched this problem for several days now and have found no solution so far. If this is just a beginners questions with a lot of answers out there I apologise, and please point me in the right directions.

I am trying to developp a "Headline" or "Banner" to be displayed at the top of my  website.

I have a colored box, in which i want to display an image (a little off the left side), right next to it some text (the name of the website) and then centered in the middle of the box again some very short text (the name of the document, Home, Contact, things like that).

So it should look like this:

<-space-><-Image-><-Website name-><----------centered text------------------------>

So far whatever I have tried just gets me this:

<-space-><-Image-><-Website name-><-text at the left--------------------------------->

I am currently using a div element for the box with three different elements so i can format them separately in the style sheet. The main problem seems to be that the last header (Centered Text) is just created around the text, and not until the right edge of the box. So aligning left, right or in the center makes no difference.

```
<div class="box blue-box ">
  <img class="icon" src="file://C:/Users/jafa/Desktop/juggling/website/images/white_design.png" alt="icon">
  <h8 class="white-text-header">Website name </h8>
  <h9 class="white-text-main-header"> Centered Text</h9>
</div>
```

with css style sheet:

```
<style>

  .blue-box {
    background-color:  #401841;
    padding: 10px;
    border:1px solid white;
    border-radius: 4px;

  .white-text-header {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: left;
  }

  .white-text-header {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
  }


  img.icon{
    width: 120px;
    height: auto;
    align-items: left;
  }
</style>
```

If anyone knows a better solution, I would be very grateful. Thank you for spending your time helping me.

Comment: you need to give width to all items

Comment: Look into flexbox (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) which is useful for these sorts of layouts or, as suggested below, there are a multitude of css frameworks which can help with this sort of thing.

Comment: By the way, `<h8>` and `<h9>` are not valid HTML tags. `<h6>` is the lowest heading size available. If you need something custom, I suggest using a `<p>` tag with a custom class like `<p class="h8">Hello!</p>`

Comment: @JoshBradley I think they're technically valid, as in, HTML5 lets you create any element you want. `<h8>` or `<h9>` won't have semantic or seo value

Comment: @sol good point. I should say that they're not part of the official HTML5 specification, and for that reason should be replaced with something more meaningful if possible. But they are technically valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You've duplicated "white-text-header" class definition. Also , left out "blue-box" class' closing brace. The code should be written as followed.

```
<style>
 .blue-box {
    background-color:  #401841;
    padding: 10px;
    border:1px solid white;
    border-radius: 4px;
 }

 .white-text-header {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: left;
 }

 .white-text-main-header {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
 }


 img.icon {
     width: 120px;
     height: auto;
     align-items: left;
 }
 </style>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer.
sorry I made those mistakes when trying to format my code for stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

h8 and h9 probably aren't the elements you want to be using. Update these and you will get what you want. You need to update your css classes. You have some bad syntax and duplicated names.

```
.blue-box {
  background-color:  #401841;
  padding: 10px;
  border:1px solid white;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.white-text-header {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
}

.white-text-main-header {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

img.icon {
  width: 120px;
  height: auto;
  align-items: left;
}
```

Here is the fiddle closer to what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/475sdf9w/26/

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer!
I am sorry the syntax and duplication errors only happened while I was trying to format the code accordingly through the stackoverflow interface and reduce it to the selection of code i wanted to post.
https://jsfiddle.net/475sdf9w/26/ is exactly what i have so far the next (and last) step would be to get the last element to be horizontally centered within the container. I think I will try out Flexbox as sol suggested and see if i can make it work.

Answer (score 0):

- h8 and h9 are not standard heading tags. [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22638799/is-it-possible-to-create-html-tags-h7-h8-h9-and-so-on)
- You can reuse text styling properties by adding the rules to the parent (`font-family`, `font-size`, and `color`.
- `font-size` needs a unit -- `24px`

You can create your layout with Flexbox. [Learn more here.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.blue-box {
  background-color: #401841;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.blue-box img {
  /* adds space to the left of the image */
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.white-text-main-header {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box blue-box ">
  <img class="icon" src="https://unsplash.it/120" alt="icon">
  <h5 class="white-text-header">Website name </h5>
  <h6 class="white-text-main-header"> Centered Text</h6>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi,
thanks for your comment. Sorry I made the formatting mistakes while formatting the code for stackoverflow. 
I have a few additional questions though:
For me adding the px for font size doesn't make a difference (works with and without) should I still add the px, and if so why?
I wanted to add the two different formats to be able to style the two elements separately. If I added the style elements to the parent element, could I still overwrite those for each element individually?

Again, thanks alot for your help, Flexbox looks great and I will try it out soon :)

Comment: You definitely need to add units to the `font-size`. If it's not making a difference, the `font-size` is correctly set somewhere else. Here's an example with --> https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/fuqzhsyp/1/  <-- If you check the developer tools you'll see that the rule is invalid.

Comment: You can keep the styles separate if you want, the only reason I added them to the parent is because they were the same and I was just reducing duplication.