# Can I use h7 tag or more than that in html?

Tags: html, css

Is there anything like h7, h8, h9. I am wondering is there is something like that.

```
<h7>Hello World!</h7>
<h8>Hello World!</h8>
```

Comment: Yes, that is more similar thank you!

Comment: [Specifically this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22638799/is-it-possible-to-create-html-tags-h7-h8-h9-and-so-on#comment98590887_22638901)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is nothing more than h6. H6 is the last heading tag in HTML.
But you can use font-size to increase or decrease the element font size.

You can do like this:

```
h1{
    font-size:500px;
}
```

or you can do it inline:

```
<h1 style="font-size:500px;">Some Text</h1>
```

If you are looking to create a tag, you can do it with some JS DOM things.
Check this answer by @Palpatim
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22638917/16786983

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22638799/is-it-possible-to-create-html-tags-h7-h8-h9-and-so-on#comment98590887_22638901